# How to count months with the same background color with formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, countif, add-on

I would like to count how many items in one column do I have in one month (for example June), that have the same color, or a specific color.
Also, I would like to sum the values from the X column that are related to the same month with the same background color.

With this formula, I managed to count a number of items from the specific month (June):

```
=ArrayFormula(countif(month('SHEET NAME'!W2:W),6))
```

So I need some conditional-like count of all items from June with the red background color. Also, I need to SUM all values from June with a red background color.

Answer (score 0):

install this add-on: **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-count](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-count-and-sum/njiklelndjpdbdngfkdgeijcpfabfgkb?utm_source=permalink)**

then use formula:

```
=COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR("B2:B21", "B2")
```

[image: 0]